# почему у меня не работает программа, нужно найти разницу элементов массива которые случайно генерируются в диапазоне

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int a = 2; /// минимальное значение массива
    const int b = 18; /// максимальное значение массива
    int subtraction;/// разнца элементов массива
    const int lenght = 7;
    int K[lenght] = {}; /// массив

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
        int K[7] = { a + rand() % (b - a + 1) }; 
        
    }


    sort(K, K + lenght);

    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
        int num1 = K[1];
        int num2 = K[2];
        int num3 = K[3];
        int num4 = K[4];
        int num5 = K[5];
        int num6 = K[6];
        int num7 = K[7];

        subtraction = num7 - num6 - num5 - num4 - num3 - num2 - num1;
        cout << subtraction;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: так и пишет "не работаю"?

Comment: Нет, выводит вот это: -858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460

Comment: ну раз что-то выводит, значит, работает.

Comment: Ох, терзает меня смутное сомнение, что "разница элементов массива" — это не совсем то, что вы считаете... Можно оригинальную постановку задачи, а не ваш пересказ? Да, если у вас проблема в выводе несколько раз одного и того же, так ваш последний цикл просто не нужен...

Comment: Создать одномерный массив К[7] и заполнить его случайными
числами от 2 до 18. Найти их разницу.

Comment: И последний цикл при таком решении не нужен, и переменные ```num_``` тоже, в общем-то, не нужны

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас исправлю

Comment: Но ошибка не в этом, сама логика не правильная и я не знаю где ее исправить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одна опечатка:

```
       int K[7] = { a + rand() % (b - a + 1) };
```

как понимаю, имелось в виду

```
       K[i] = { a + rand() % (b - a + 1) };
```

И одна ошибка: индексы массива идут от 0 до `length-1`,  а у Вас дважды встречается `K[7]`, что является выходом за пределы массива

Comment: Если я меняю К[7] на K[i]то выдает ошибку, что невозможно использовать как константу

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, полный текст ошибки

Comment: выражение должно иметь константное значение

Comment: И я не совсем понял, где у меня выходит значение за пределы массива, там где subtraction?

Comment: Не существует индекса 7 в массиве из семи элементов. Обе строки, содержащие ```K[7]``` - с ошибкой. Выход за пределы массива

Comment: Поправил ответ, посмотрите. Не надо снова указывать тип, Вы тем самым в теле цикла создаете новую переменную, не имеющую ничего общего с тем ```int K[length]```, что объявляете в начале

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо вам огромное

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста  :)